# Is metacognition an affective, cognitive, or behavioural variable?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, metacognition

Is metacognition an affect or cognitive or behaviour variable ?

I want to study variation in metacognition and working memory ability level and its effect on inductive reasoning. 
Therefore i am trying to understand the cognitive system.
I read some literature stating that metacognition is cognition awareness, which implies that it is a cognitive variable, but some say that it is an opinion about how far they can do metacognitive ability. I read about a factor analysis of the Junior Metacognitive Awareness Inventory.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like there are a lot of ideas out there as to what `metacognition` really is.  Having done my MS thesis in understanding how people learn in engineering programs, I typically think about metacognition as "knowing how to learn."  It's typically a goal of engineering education to teach students these skills.

Therefore, I would say it's mostly a cognitive variable, but it's also a behavior because it's a set of habits about how one thinks.  How are you planning to measure metacognition?  And why inductive reasoning?  Why not critical thinking in general?

Comment: I used Junior Metacognitive Awareness Inventory (Sperling, Howard, Miller, & Murphy, 2002), a children version of Metacognitive Awareness Inventory by Schraw and Dennison. Pls explain of what further of what you say  “And why inductive reasoning? Why not critical thinking in general?”.

Comment: You want to study the relationship on inductive reasoning, I'm curious if you have a specific reason why?

Comment: Basically I want to know if metacognitive ability able to override the limitation of working memory in inductive reasoning performance among children developmentally. Well this is my dissertation topic, I model my as research question as - age (IV), working memory (mediator 1) , metacognitive (mediator 2), and inductive reasoning performance (DV).

Comment: Interesting. From what I know of working memory, I would expect that high metacognitive abilities would help the subject to exclude irrelevant chunks from WM. Would this be considered "overriding"?  What ages are you targeting?

Comment: Yes that what I mean, but research wise not quite the right word to describe the phenomenon. Maybe says I want to see the variance of both mediator effect to inductive reasoning. Children, the age where Piaget theorize as borderline between operational and formal, difference between pupil aged 10-11 and 13-14. I want to ask since your research more on seeing the larger picture, do you know what connection between higher order thinking (HOT) and inductive reasoning.

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of connections, though I'm not sure whether or not they have been studied. My research focuses on critical thinking skills, of which inductive reasoning would certainly be a sub-component. However, for the age group you target, CT skills probably aren't very well developed yet, so looking at the subcomponents might make more sense. I don't know, this is all conjecture from me.